# Burning a Ubuntu install disk on Mac

Tags: macbook

When I downloaded the latest Ubuntu .iso, I went to burn it on my Mac to be able to dual boot into Ubuntu using bootcamp, so the disk burned fine, but when it finished, it said my computer couldn't read it. Why is this?

Comment: Have a look at [How to burn a DVD on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx)

Comment: I've soon that and idk what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer doesn't have to read it at that moment, so ignore that message.
Also, you can't use bootcamp for Ubuntu, bootcamp is only for Windows.

Anyway, it's a bad idea to install Ubuntu on a Mac using a CD since that creates a wrong type of install.

This is how to install Ubuntu correctly on your Mac:

1. Grab an USB stick and format it as FAT using Disk Utility. If it already is FAT, still format it so it's free of data. WARNING, ALL FILES ON THE USB STICK WILL BE LOST (but that's obvious)
2. Plug out all of your USB drives (if you have them) except the USB stick you just formatted.
3. [Download UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).
4. Launch UNetbootin, enter admin password when prompted, click the round button next to the word ISO, click ... , select the ISO.
5. Click OK.
6. Wait until a message that the USB stick will not boot of a Mac appears. Ignore it. Click exit.
7. Turn off your Mac with the USB stick still in it
8. Turn on your Mac while pressing the ALT key.
9. Choose "EFI Boot" in the menu that appears.
10. Ubuntu installer appears! You can now install Ubuntu. Don't pull out the USB stick until the installation is done.
11. (OPTIONAL BUT RECOMMENDED) When installed, it's a good idea to launch the Additional Drivers program to install additional graphics drivers (but avoid the expirimental ones). This will increase performance and battery life.

To choose whether to boot to Mac OS X or Ubuntu during startup, hold the ALT key while turning on your Mac. This will show a menu where you can choose a partition to boot from.